# progress dialog circle only showing after task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i've an progress circle that is set inside an AsyncTask. It shows for about a second as the asynctask is executing, then disappears. once the task is completed if i press the back button the circle shows for a long time. why is this?

```
private class AsyncGetRota extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(NfcscannerActivity.this, 
                    "Connecting to Server"," retrieving rota...", true);

            //do initialization of required objects objects here                
        };      


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {



            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");
                rotaArray = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getRota(params[0], params[1]);

                cancel(true);



            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        };



    }
```

[update]

```
getRota.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onclicked getRota");

                    String[] params = new String[]{"36", "18-09-2012"}; 
                    AsyncGetRota agr = new AsyncGetRota();
                    agr.execute(params);

                    for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){

                        if(agr.isCancelled() == true){
                            Log.e(TAG, "asyncTask is finished");
                            break;
                        }


                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }//end of for loop

                    Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                            GetRota.class);

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("rotaArray", rotaArray);

                    intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }// end of onclick
            });
```

Comment: What for do you call cancel()?

Comment: @egor there is no guarantee that the asynctask is completed from the calling activity. the asynctask sets some variables in the calling class so i only process these variable AFTER the task has finished. So cancel is checked from the activity

Comment: you can do that processing in onPostExecute() why check in activity? If you want to stop asynctask at some point, do return. dont call cancel..

Comment: @userSeven7s I know what you're saying but for some reason the calling activity continued to process these variables before the task had completed, this is when i had a postExecute. post execute was not setting the variables in time. so i chose to tell the activity when it had completed. the task is making a network call to a webservice.

Comment: Can you add the method code where you start this asynctask? Are you checking it in a while loop on UI thread?

Comment: See the answer I added... Dont use a loop to wait for the asynctask's results.. you can pass the results to the `onPostExecute()` by returning from `doInBackground()`..

Comment: @userSeven7s thanks, i did try that before(using postExecute), but for some reason the instance variables weren't being set from postExecute, so i tried a workaround. It obviously backfired when i tried to implement progress circle. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
new MyAsyncTask().execute(string);
...
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Whatever > {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Whatever doInBackground(String... params) {

       Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");
       rotaArray = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getRota(params[0],       params[1]);
       return rotaArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Whatever result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this, GetRota.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("rotaArray", result);

        intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You should let the execution continue after you start the AsyncTask, and not block it using some loop or something..

Answer (score 0):

try to implement it like this:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
   dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
   dialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   if (dialog.isShowing()) {
       dialog.dismiss();
   } 
};
```

that's always works for me

Comment: no sorry still the same i'm afraid. It shows up breifley then when back button pressed it stays on

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here, you do not initialize ProgressDialog, initialize a constructor that initializes you ProgressDialog like this...

```
 public AsyncGetRota(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }
```

Then in onPostExecute check if your ProgressDialog is null, like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```